# PHP not returning all variables on string from $_POST

Tags: php, html, variables, post

My problem is, my get string function is not returning all of the variables, only the first 16. This worked fine for me before, but I am unsure what I have changed to make it not work correctly.

You can visit http://gen.emudevs.com/index.php?p=tc_creature and viewsource to see my form input's.

Here is the action PHP the form is submitted to:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('tc_func.php');
$trinityFunc = new TrinityCoreFunc();

$trinityFunc->entry = $_POST['entryId'];
$trinityFunc->name = $_POST['name_val'];
$trinityFunc->subname = $_POST['subname'];
$trinityFunc->modelid1 = $_POST['DisplayId1'];
$trinityFunc->modelid2 = $_POST['DisplayId2'];
$trinityFunc->modelid3 = $_POST['DisplayId3'];
$trinityFunc->modelid4 = $_POST['DisplayId4'];
$trinityFunc->minLevel = $_POST['minlevel'];
$trinityFunc->maxLevel = $_POST['maxlevel'];
$trinityFunc->faction_A = $_POST['alliance'];
$trinityFunc->faction_H = $_POST['horde'];
$trinityFunc->scale = $_POST['scale'];
$trinityFunc->rank = $_POST['ranks'];
$trinityFunc->dmg_multiplier = $_POST['dmgmultiplier'];
$trinityFunc->mindmg = $_POST['mindamage'];
$trinityFunc->maxdmg = $_POST['maxdamage'];
$trinityFunc->attacktime = $_POST['attacktime'];
$trinityFunc->health = $_POST['health'];
$trinityFunc->mana = $_POST['mana'];
$trinityFunc->armor = $_POST['armor'];
$trinityFunc->movementId = $_POST['movementid'];
$trinityFunc->lootid = $_POST['lootid'];
$trinityFunc->movementtype = $_POST['movementtype'];
$trinityFunc->vehicleId = $_POST['vehicleid'];
$trinityFunc->mingold = $_POST['mingold'];
$trinityFunc->maxgold = $_POST['maxgold'];
$trinityFunc->equipmentId = $_POST['equipmentid'];
$trinityFunc->resistance = $_POST['resistance1'];
$trinityFunc->resistance2 = $_POST['resistance2'];
$trinityFunc->resistance3 = $_POST['resistance3'];
$trinityFunc->resistance4 = $_POST['resistance4'];
$trinityFunc->resistance5 = $_POST['resistance5'];
$trinityFunc->resistance6 = $_POST['resistance6'];
$trinityFunc->scriptname = $_POST['scriptname'];
$trinityFunc->AIName = $_POST['ainame'];
/* TYPE */
switch ($_POST['tctype_option'])
{
    case "None":
        $trinityFunc->type = 0;
        break;
    case "Beast":
        $trinityFunc->type = 1;
        break;
    case "Dragonkin":
        $trinityFunc->type = 2;
        break;
    case "Demon":
        $trinityFunc->type = 3;
        break;
    case "Elemental":
        $trinityFunc->type = 4;
        break;
    case "Giant":
        $trinityFunc->type = 5;
        break;
    case "Undead":
        $trinityFunc->type = 6;
        break;
    case "Humanoid":
        $trinityFunc->type = 7;
        break;
    case "Critter":
        $trinityFunc->type = 8;
        break;
    case "Mechanical":
        $trinityFunc->type = 9;
        break;
    case "Not Specified":
        $trinityFunc->type = 10;
        break;
    case "Totem":
        $trinityFunc->type = 11;
        break;
    case "Non-Combat Pet":
        $trinityFunc->type = 12;
        break;
    case "Gas Cloud":
        $trinityFunc->type = 13;
        break;
}
/* FAMILY */
switch ($_POST['tcfamily_option']) // $trinityFunc->family
{
    case "None":
        $trinityFunc->family = 0;
        break;
    case "Wolf":
        $trinityFunc->family = 1;
        break;
    case "Cat":
        $trinityFunc->family = 2;
        break;
    case "Spider":
        $trinityFunc->family = 3;
        break;
    case "Bear":
        $trinityFunc->family = 4;
        break;
    case "Boar":
        $trinityFunc->family = 5;
        break;
    case "Crocolisk":
        $trinityFunc->family = 6;
        break;
    case "Carrion Bird":
        $trinityFunc->family = 7;
        break;
    case "Crab":
        $trinityFunc->family = 8;
        break;
    case "Gorilla":
        $trinityFunc->family = 9;
        break;
    case "Raptor":
        $trinityFunc->family = 11;
        break;
    case "Tallstrider":
        $trinityFunc->family = 12;
        break;
    case "Felhunter":
        $trinityFunc->family = 15;
        break;
    case "Voidwalker":
        $trinityFunc->family = 16;
        break;
    case "Succubus":
        $trinityFunc->family = 17;
        break;
    case "Doomguard":
        $trinityFunc->family = 19;
        break;
    case "Scorpid":
        $trinityFunc->family = 20;
        break;
    case "Turtle":
        $trinityFunc->family = 21;
        break;
    case "Imp":
        $trinityFunc->family = 23;
        break;
    case "Bat":
        $trinityFunc->family = 24;
        break;
    case "Hyena":
        $trinityFunc->family = 25;
        break;
    case "Owl":
        $trinityFunc->family = 26;
        break;
    case "Wind Serpent":
        $trinityFunc->family = 27;
        break;
    case "Remote Control":
        $trinityFunc->family = 28;
        break;
    case "Felguard":
        $trinityFunc->family = 29;
        break;
    case "Dragonhawk":
        $trinityFunc->family = 30;
        break;
    case "Ravager":
        $trinityFunc->family = 31;
        break;
    case "Warp Stalker":
        $trinityFunc->family = 32;
        break;
    case "Sporebat":
        $trinityFunc->family = 33;
        break;
    case "Nether Ray":
        $trinityFunc->family = 34;
        break;
    case "Serpent":
        $trinityFunc->family = 35;
        break;
    case "Moth":
        $trinityFunc->family = 37;
        break;
    case "Chimaera":
        $trinityFunc->family = 38;
        break;
    case "Devilsaur":
        $trinityFunc->family = 39;
        break;
    case "Ghoul":
        $trinityFunc->family = 40;
        break;
    case "Silithid":
        $trinityFunc->family = 41;
        break;
    case "Worm":
        $trinityFunc->family = 42;
        break;
    case "Rhino":
        $trinityFunc->family = 43;
        break;
    case "Wasp":
        $trinityFunc->family = 44;
        break;
    case "Core Hound":
        $trinityFunc->family = 45;
        break;
    case "Spirit Beast":
        $trinityFunc->family = 46;
        break;
}
/* UNIT CLASS */
switch ($_POST['tcclass_option']) // $trinityFunc->unit_class
{
    case "None":
        $trinityFunc->unit_class = 0;
        break;
    case "Warrior":
        $trinityFunc->unit_class = 1;
        break;
    case "Paladin":
        $trinityFunc->unit_class = 2;
        break;
    case "Rogue":
        $trinityFunc->unit_class = 4;
        break;
    case "Mage":
        $trinityFunc->unit_class = 8;
        break;
}
/* NPC FLAG */
switch ($_POST['tcflag_option']) // $trinityFunc->npcflag
{
    case "None":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 0;
        break;
    case "Gossip":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 1;
        break;
    case "Quest Giver":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 2;
        break;
    case "Trainer":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 16;
        break;
    case "Profession Trainer":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 64;
        break;
    case "Vendor":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 128;
        break;
    case "Gossip & Vendor":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 129;
        break;
    case "Vendor Ammo":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 256;
        break;
    case "Vendor Food":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 512;
        break;
    case "Vendor Poison":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 1024;
        break;
    case "Vendor Reagent":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 2048;
        break;
    case "Repairer":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 4096;
        break;
    case "Flight Master":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 8192;
        break;
    case "Spirit Healer":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 16384;
        break;
    case "Spirit Guide":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 32768;
        break;
    case "Innkeeper":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 65536;
        break;
    case "Banker":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 131072;
        break;
    case "Petitioner":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 262144;
        break;
    case "Tabard Designer":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 524288;
        break;
    case "Battlemaster":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 1048576;
        break;
    case "Auctioneer":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 2097152;
        break;
    case "Stable Master":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 4194304;
        break;
    case "Guild Banker":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 8388608;
        break;
    case "Spellclick":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 16777216;
        break;
    case "Mailbox":
        $trinityFunc->npcflag = 67108864;
        break;
}
/* UNIT FLAGS */
switch ($_POST['tcunitflag_option']) // $trinityFunc->unit_flags
{
    case "None":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 0;
        break;
    case "Server Controlled":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 1;
        break;
    case "Not Attackable":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 2;
        break;
    case "Disable Movement":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 4;
        break;
    case "PvP Attackable":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 8;
        break;
    case "Rename":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 16;
        break;
    case "Preparation":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 32;
        break;
    case "Not Attackable_1":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 128;
        break;
    case "Immune to PC":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 256;
        break;
    case "Immune to NPC":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 512;
        break;
    case "Looting":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 1024;
        break;
    case "Pet in Combat":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 2048;
        break;
    case "PvP":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 4096;
        break;
    case "Silenced":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 8192;
        break;
    case "Pacified":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 131072;
        break;
    case "Stunned":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 262144;
        break;
    case "In Combat":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 524288;
        break;
    case "Taxi Flight":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 1048576;
        break;
    case "Disarmed":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 2097152;
        break;
    case "Confused":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 4194304;
        break;
    case "Fleeing":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 8388608;
        break;
    case "Player Controlled":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 16777216;
        break;
    case "Not Selectable":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 33554432;
        break;
    case "Skinnable":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 67108864;
        break;
    case "Mount":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 134217728;
        break;
    case "Sheathe":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags = 1073741824;
        break;
}
/* UNIT FLAGS TWO */
switch ($_POST['tcunitflag2_option']) // $trinityFunc->unit_flags2
{
    case "None":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags2 = 0;
        break;
    case "Feign Death":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags2 = 1;
        break;
    case "Ignore Reputation":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags2 = 4;
        break;
    case "Comprehend Language":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags2 = 8;
        break;
    case "Mirror Image":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags2 = 16;
        break;
    case "Force Move":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags2 = 64;
        break;
    case "Disarm Offhand":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags2 = 128;
        break;
    case "Disarm Ranged":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags2 = 1024;
        break;
    case "Regenerate Power":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags2 = 2048;
        break;
    case "Allow Enemy Interact":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags2 = 16384;
        break;
    case "Allow Cheat Spells":
        $trinityFunc->unit_flags2 = 262144;
        break;
}
/* TYPE FLAGS */
switch ($_POST['tctypeflag_option']) // $trinityFunc->type_flags
{
    case "None":
        $trinityFunc->type_flags = 0;
        break;
    case "Tamable":
        $trinityFunc->type_flags = 1;
        break;
    case "Ghost":
        $trinityFunc->type_flags = 2;
        break;
    case "Dead Interact":
        $trinityFunc->type_flags = 128;
        break;
    case "Herb Loot":
        $trinityFunc->type_flags = 256;
        break;
    case "Mining Loot":
        $trinityFunc->type_flags = 512;
        break;
    case "Mounted Combat":
        $trinityFunc->type_flags = 2048;
        break;
    case "Aid Players":
        $trinityFunc->type_flags = 4096;
        break;
    case "Engineer Loot":
        $trinityFunc->type_flags = 32768;
        break;
    case "Exotic":
        $trinityFunc->type_flags = 65536;
        break;
}
/* EXTRA FLAGS */
switch ($_POST['tcextraflag_option']) // $trinityFunc->extraflags
{
    case "None":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 0;
        break;
    case "Instance Bind":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 1;
        break;
    case "Civilian":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 2;
        break;
    case "Don't Parry":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 4;
        break;
    case "Don't Counter Attack w/Parry":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 8;
        break;
    case "Don't Block":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 16;
        break;
    case "Don't Crush":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 32;
        break;
    case "Don't give XP":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 64;
        break;
    case "Trigger":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 128;
        break;
    case "Immune to taunt auras":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 256;
        break;
    case "World Event":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 16384;
        break;
    case "Guard":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 32768;
        break;
    case "Don't Crit":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 131072;
        break;
    case "Don't Gain Skill":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 262144;
        break;
    case "Taunt Dimnish":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 524288;
        break;
    case "All Dimnish":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 1048576;
        break;
    case "Dungeon Boss":
        $trinityFunc->extraflags = 2097152;
        break;
}
/* MECHANIC IMMUNE MASK */
switch ($_POST['tcimmune_option']) // $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask
{
    case "None":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 0;
        break;
    case "ALL":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 2147483647;
        break;
    case "Charm":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 1;
        break;
    case "Disoriented":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 2;
        break;
    case "Disarm":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 4;
        break;
    case "Distract":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 8;
        break;
    case "Fear":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 16;
        break;
    case "Grip":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 32;
        break;
    case "Root":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 64;
        break;
    case "Pacify":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 128;
        break;
    case "Silence":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 256;
        break;
    case "Sleep":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 512;
        break;
    case "Snare":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 1024;
        break;
    case "Stun":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 2048;
        break;
    case "Freeze":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 4096;
        break;
    case "Knockout":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 8192;
        break;
    case "Bleed":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 16384;
        break;
    case "Bandage":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 32768;
        break;
    case "Polymorph":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 65536;
        break;
    case "Banish":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 131072;
        break;
    case "Shield":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 262144;
        break;
    case "Shackle":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 524288;
        break;
    case "Mount":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 1048576;
        break;
    case "Infected":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 2097152;
        break;
    case "Turn":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 4194304;
        break;
    case "Horror":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 8388608;
        break;
    case "Invulnerability":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 16777216;
        break;
    case "Interrupt":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 33554432;
        break;
    case "Daze":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 67108864;
        break;
    case "Discovery":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 134217728;
        break;
    case "Immune Shield":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 268435456;
        break;
    case "Sapped":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 536870912;
        break;
    case "Enraged":
        $trinityFunc->mechanic_immune_mask = 1073741824;
        break;
}

foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
    echo "Param: $param_name Value: $param_val<br />\n";
}
```

The foreach is there to just test the returned values

This is the included tc_func.php which generates the info:

```
<?php
session_start();

class TrinityCoreFunc
{
    /* Creature Template */
    var $creatureTemplateStructure;
    var $entry, $modelid1, $modelid2, $modelid3, $modelid4, $name, $subname, $minLevel, $maxLevel, $faction_A, $faction_H, $npcflag, $scale, $rank, $mindmg, $maxdmg, $dmg_multiplier, $attacktime,
    $unit_class, $unit_flags, $unit_flags2, $family, $type, $type_flags, $lootid, $resistance, $resistance2, $resistance3, $resistance4, $resistance5, $resistance6, $vehicleId, $mingold, $maxgold,
    $AIName, $movementtype, $health, $mana, $armor, $movementId, $equipmentId, $mechanic_immune_mask, $extraflags, $scriptname;

    // Generator
    var $generateStructure;

    function TrinityCoreFunc()
    {
        /* Creature Template */
        $this->creatureTemplateStructure = array("INSERT INTO `creature_template` (`entry`,", "`difficulty_entry_1`,", "`difficulty_entry_2`,", "`difficulty_entry_3`,", "`KillCredit1`,", "`KillCredit2`,",
            "`modelid1`,", "`modelid2`,", "`modelid3`,", "`modelid4`,", "`name`,", "`subname`,", "`IconName`,", "`gossip_menu_id`,", "`minlevel`,", "`maxlevel`,", "`exp`,", "`faction_A`,", "`faction_H`,",
            "`npcflag`,", "`speed_walk`,", "`speed_run`,", "`scale`,", "`rank`,", "`mindmg`,", "`maxdmg`,", "`dmgschool`,", "`attackpower`,","`dmg_multiplier`,", "`baseattacktime`,", "`rangeattacktime`,",
            "`unit_class`,", "`unit_flags`,", "`unit_flags2`,", "`dynamicflags`,", "`family`,", "`trainer_type`,", "`trainer_spell`,", "`trainer_class`,", "`trainer_race`,", "`minrangedmg`,", "`maxrangedmg`,",
            "`rangedattackpower`,", "`type`,", "`type_flags`,", "`lootid`,", "`pickpocketloot`,", "`skinloot`,", "`resistance1`,", "`resistance2`,", "`resistance3`,", "`resistance4`,", "`resistance5`,",
            "`resistance6`,", "`spell1`,", "`spell2`,", "`spell3`,", "`spell4`,", "`spell5`,", "`spell6`,", "`spell7`,", "`spell8`,", "`PetSpellDataId`,", "`VehicleId`,", "`mingold`,", "`maxgold`,", "`AIName`,",
            "`MovementType`,", "`InhabitType`,", "`HoverHeight`,", "`Health_mod`,", "`Mana_mod`,", "`Armor_mod`,", "`RacialLeader`,", "`questItem1`,", "`questItem2`,", "`questItem3`,", "`questItem4`,", "`questItem5`,",
            "`questItem6`,", "`movementId`,", "`RegenHealth`,", "`equipment_id`,", "`mechanic_immune_mask`,", "`flags_extra`,", "`ScriptName`,", "`WDBVerified`) VALUES (");
        /* End Creature Template */

        $this->entry = 0;
        $this->modelid1 = 0;
        $this->modelid2 = 0;
        $this->modelid3 = 0;
        $this->modelid4 = 0;
        $this->name = "";
        $this->subname = "";
        $this->minLevel = 0;
        $this->maxLevel = 0;
        $this->faction_A = 0;
        $this->faction_H = 0;
        $this->npcflag = 0;
        $this->scale = 1;
        $this->rank = 0;
        $this->mindmg = 0;
        $this->maxdmg = 0;
        $this->dmg_multiplier = 0;
        $this->attacktime = 2000;
        $this->unit_class = 0;
        $this->unit_flags = 0;
        $this->unit_flags2 = 0;
        $this->family = 0;
        $this->type = 0;
        $this->type_flags = 0;
        $this->lootid = 0;
        $this->resistance = 0;
        $this->resistance2 = 0;
        $this->resistance3 = 0;
        $this->resistance4 = 0;
        $this->resistance5 = 0;
        $this->resistance6 = 0;
        $this->vehicleId = 0;
        $this->mingold = 0;
        $this->maxgold = 0;
        $this->AIName = "";
        $this->movementtype = 0;
        $this->health = 0;
        $this->mana = 0;
        $this->armor = 0;
        $this->movementId = 0;
        $this->equipmentId = 0;
        $this->mechanic_immune_mask = 0;
        $this->extraflags = 0;
        $this->scriptname = "";
    }

    function GetCreatureGenerateStructure()
    {
        $this->generateStructure = $this->entry . ", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, " . $this->modelid1 . ", " . $this->modelid2 . ", " . $this->modelid3 . ", " . $this->modelid4 . ", '" . $this->name . "', '"
        . $this->subname . "', '', 0, " . $this->minLevel . ", " . $this->maxLevel . ", 0, " . $this->faction_A . ", " . $this->faction_H . ", " . $this->npcflag . ", 1, 1, " . $this->scale . ", " . $this->rank . ", "
        . $this->mindmg . ", " . $this->maxdmg . ", 0, 0, " . $this->dmg_multiplier . ", " . $this->attacktime . ", 2000, " . $this-> unit_class . ", " . $this->unit_flags . ", " . $this->unit_flags2 . ", 8, "
        . $this->family . ", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, " . $this->type . ", " . $this->type_flags . ", " . $this->lootid . ", 0, 0, " . $this->resistance . ", " . $this->resistance2 . ", "
        . $this->resistance3 . ", " . $this->resistance4 . ", " . $this->resistance5 . ", " . $this->resistance6 . ", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, " . $this->vehicleId . ", " . $this->mingold . ", "
        . $this->maxgold . ", '" . $this->AIName . "', 1, 1, 1, " . $this->health . ", " . $this->mana . ", " . $this->armor . ", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, " . $this->movementId . ", 1, "
        . $this->equipmentId . ", " . $this->mechanic_immune_mask . ", " . $this->extraflags . ", '" . $this->scriptname . "', 1);";

        return $this->generateStructure;
    }

    function GetCreatureTemplateStructure()
    {
        $val = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->creatureTemplateStructure); $i++)
        {
            $val .= $this->creatureTemplateStructure[$i];
        }
        return $val;
    }
}
```

So the problem is, returning generateStructure from GetCreatureGenerateStructure only gives the first 16 posted variables and the rest show blank.

I hope there is someone here who can see something that I am not. Iv'e been stressing with this for over a week now and I am out of ideas.

Comment: What does `echo ini_get('max_input_vars');` output?

Comment: It looks to me like your form is only sending 16 values, so PHP won't get more. Your form has some issues with malformed HTML (embedded forms aren't permitted, for example), and you're loading two different versions of jQuery, which also won't help you. Take a look at the page source in Firefox and fix anything you see in red.

Comment: That was it Mike W, thank you. I downloaded FireFox and looked at the page source. It was the <form> tag I wrapped around one of my buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the html inspector some the fields are not actually in your form hence they will not be submitted.